# Engineering PDE. Question about separation constant

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations

I have an engineering PDE (a Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates):
$$\frac{1}{r}P_r+P_{rr} +P_{zz}=0$$
For:
$$P(r,z)=R(r)Z(z)$$
With BCs:
$$P(r,\pm \infty)=0\text{ and }P(+\infty, z)=0$$
$$P(R_o,z)=V_1\text{ and }P(r,\pm L/2)=V_2$$
Separation of variables:

$$\frac1r Z R'+Z R''+ \frac{1}{r^2}R Z''=0$$

$$\frac1r\frac{R'}{R}+\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{Z''}{Z}=0$$

$$r\frac{R'}{R}+r^2\frac{R''}{R}=-\frac{Z''}{Z}=-\lambda^2$$
I'm assuming the separation constant to be $< 0$ (a guess), so that:
$$r^2 R''+rR'+\lambda^2R=0$$
$$Z''-\lambda^2Z=0$$
Re. the $Z(z)$ ODE, because of the $\infty$ BC, we assume $c_1$ to be zero:
$$Z(z)=c_1 e^{\lambda z}+c_2e^{-\lambda z}$$
$$c_1=0 \Rightarrow Z(z)=c_2e^{-\lambda z}$$
But with the $R(r)$ ODE something undesirable happens.
$$r^2R''+rR'+\lambda^2 R=0$$
Assume:
$$R=r^m$$
$$R'=mr^{m-1}$$
$$R''=m(m-1)r^{m-2}$$
$$m^2+\lambda^2=0$$
$$m=\pm \lambda i$$
So that:
$$R(r)=c_3\cos(\lambda \ln r)+c_4\sin(\lambda \ln r)$$
**But that function has a singularity for** $r=0$, which is unacceptable!

If I switch to a separation constant of $+\lambda^2$, then the function $Z(z)$ becomes:

$$Z(z)=A\sin mz+B \cos mz$$

Which is undetermined for $z \to \pm \infty$

Help!

Comment: Yes, of course. Stupid typo. Thanks!

Comment: You do have the option of $\lambda=0$ as well. But this doesn't seem to help much. Another question: Is $r\to-\infty$ of interest, or are you only focused on $r\geq 0$?

Comment: No, I did try that too.

Comment: Is this supposed to be cylindrical coordinates? If so, then $r<0$ is very much -not- of interest: $x<0$ corresponds to $\theta=\pi$, not $r<0$.

Comment: Sorry: my bad. It is in CC, so $r<0$ is not possible.

Comment: Do you have the original statement of the problem? That may clarify what boundary conditions are physically meaningful.

Comment: I avoid posting physics problems here. The problem was posted at P.SE and we just ran into these math problems. In terms of math, rest assured, the problem is correctly stated. We're looking for the electrical potential $P$ *outside* of a cylinder with uniform electrical charge.

Comment: In that case: Why do you care about $r\leq r_0$? The blow-up at $r=0$ is irrelevant in that domain.

Comment: For $z>|\pm L/2|$, $r<R_o$ does have meaning